# How to horizontally center text(h2)? I have problems

Tags: html, css

I have some trouble with getting text centering in my website, for some reason. I need the text to be exactly centered in the website, both computer and website.

```css
.bg { 
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/HrC81SX.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }

#cs {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    position: absolute;
    color: #EFE4D9;
}

#text {
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<h1 id="cs" style="text-align: center;">C O M I N G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S O O N</h1>
<p id="text">such's movie room is on it's way through the development, just stay tuned! C:<br>- such <3</p>
```

Comment: Remove the position absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.bg { 
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/HrC81SX.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    z-index:0;
  }

#cs {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    position: relative;
    color: #EFE4D9;  
}

#text {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This one worked! Just 1 line, and that is it! Thank you! C:

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```css
.bg { 
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/HrC81SX.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
    z-index:0;
  }

#cs {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    position: relative;
    color: #EFE4D9;  
}

#text {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <h1 id="cs" style="text-align: center;">C O M I N G&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S O O N</h1>
        <p id="text">such's movie room is on it's way through the development, just stay tuned! C:<br>- such <3</p>
        <!--a countdown should be here-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why downvote in my answer? what's wrong in this answer?